# Custom load balancing on Heroku for beta testing

Tags: node.js, heroku, next.js

Our site, on Heroku, is gaining a lot of usage lately and I'm thinking about DevOps stuff more and more. One thing I would like to look into is the ability to have a beta tier that 5-10% of users hit where we they get a newer version of our app before it goes out to 100% of users so we can try to detect regressions sooner. Does anyone know if Heroku offers any sort of advanced configuration that would allow this?

The only solution I can come up with is more of a manual approach where I specifically designate a subselection of users and redirect them to the beta tier (separate subdomain, separate heroku app). But before I build something like this, I was curious what is already available/standard practice for such things. This is definitely out of my normal area of expertise so I'm not sure where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The setup is NextJS server, React frontend, currently living on one Heroku app.